# Regex multiple occurrences of same character Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a problem with isolating a dynamic string+int occurrence in a text:

I want to capture "k9034", the first char is always a string, the length of the following int can vary in length "9034...76"

Given:

`K:\dir1\executions\` is static and always the same
the number of \ is always the same in the full text

So far I have made a script:

```
^K.*executions\\([a-t])
```

It captures `K:\dir1\executions\` in match 1 and `k` in group 1

Since k9034 varies in length I would like to write something like:

```
^K.*executions\\([a-t].*)\\.*
```

For "\.*" I would like to capture the first `\` after k9034 and put it in a match or other group(\.*), but with my script it captures the wrong \

Im using regex101.com to test it.

```
K:\dir1\executions\k9034\kejlk34f\fdshf3\
```

Best regards

H

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it either using 2 capture groups:

```
^K:\\[^\s\\]+\\executions(\\[a-t]\d+)(\\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YT7GPZ/1)

Or use a single capture group

```
^K:\\[^\s\\]+\\executions(\\[a-t]\d+\\)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `K:\\` Match `K:\`
- `[^\s\\]+` Match 1+ chars other than `\` or whitespace chars
- `\\executions` Match `\executions`
- `(\\[a-t]\d+\\)` Capture **group 1**, match `\` then a single char in the range a-t and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OFByfH/1)